# Rails Nested collection_select appears in HTML but not on screen

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

Ok.  Weird problem here.  I'm building a nested form in rails and it looks fine when I examine the html and view page source, but the drop down doesn't appear for the collection_select option.  Again, I can see all of my  options in the html, but in the actual window, the drop down isn't there.  It's almost as if I have it set the CSS to display: none; which I don't.

Here's the nested form code:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  Countertops:

<%= f.fields_for :countertops, Countertop.new do |countertops_form| %>

<div class="form-group" align="left">
    <%= countertops_form.label :counterzip, "Tell us where your countertop project is going." %>
    <%= countertops_form.text_field :counterzip, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter your Zip Code" %>
</div>

<div id="countertype" class="form-group" align="left">
    <%= countertops_form.label :countertype_id, "What type of countertop material do you need?" %></br>
    <%= countertops_form.collection_select :countertype_id, Countertype.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Select Your Material" }, class: "input-sm"  %>
</div>

<% end %>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And here's the resulting HTML for the collection_select.

```
<div id="countertype" class="form-group" align="left">
    <label for="project_countertops_attributes_0_countertype_id">What type of countertop material do you need?</label></br>
    <select class="input-sm" name="project[countertops_attributes][0][countertype_id]" id="project_countertops_attributes_0_countertype_id">
<option value="">Select Your Material</option>
<option value="1">Granite</option>
<option value="2">Marble</option>
<option value="3">Soapstone</option>
<option value="4">Wood</option>
<option value="5">Quartz</option>
<option value="6">Concrete</option></select>
  </div>
```

So why can't I see this on the page when it's loaded?  I can see the label and I can see the form for the first field.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on getting it working - `fields_for` can be tricky, but I see you have it working quite well here. Your HTML looks correct too.

---

If you're not seeing the element on screen, there are two potentialities:

**CSS**

You mention the CSS should be okay.

*Never* underestimate the nuances of CSS. I see you have the following:

```
<div id="countertype" class="form-group" align="left">
    <%= countertops_form.label :countertype_id, "What type of countertop material do you need?" %></br>
    <%= countertops_form.collection_select :countertype_id, Countertype.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Select Your Material" }, class: "input-sm"  %>
</div>
```

I would *highly* recommend trying it without any CSS:

```
<div>
   <%= countertops_form.collection_select :countertype_id, Countertype.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => "Select Your Material" }  %>
</div>
```

-

**`fields_for`**

The other issue you have is `fields_for` - you're passing `Countertop.new` to the method. Whilst there should be no problem with this, I've had problems before doing stuff like that.

If you absolutely wanted to pass a new `fields_for` object, you should build it in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @project = Project.new
      @project.countertops.build
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following HTML:

```
<%= f.fields_for :countertops do |countertops_form| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rich.  You've been a big help so far with my project.  I'll give your suggestions a try and report back.